# Can't build assets after upgrading Vue to v3.4.3 (On a Laravel v8.75 project using Webpack)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to upgrade Vue to it's latest version 3.4.3 to be able, among other things, to use the new defineModel macro. I upgraded vue-tsc and vue-loader as recommended in the blog. However now, when i run `npm run watch` or `npm run prod`, I get the following webpack error : `[webpack-cli] Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue requires vue (>=3.2.13) or @vue/compiler-sfc to be present in the dependency tree.`

The site is a Laravel v8.75 using Webpack/Laravel Mix to build assets.

Here's my package.json :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "axios": "^0.26.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.43",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.4.32",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.62.0",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
        "typescript": "^5.0.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^40.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^5.1.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.0",
        "eslint": "^8.39.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.19.2",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
        "mdb-ui-kit": "^3.5.1",
        "moment": "^2.30.1",
        "node-snackbar": "^0.1.16",
        "std-env": "^3.1.1",
        "vue": "^3.4.3",
        "vue-loader": "^17.4.0",
        "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
        "vue-tsc": "^1.8.27"
    }
}
```

I had `"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.47"` in my dependencies but removed it as i understood it was already in the vue module. Installing it back, resulting in the `"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.4.3",` in my dependencies, didn't change the above webpack error. And I'm not gonna install Vite for this project.

Any clue what I should do?